# Open source database migration tools that support raw SQL

Tags: database, database-migration

I am trying to build a tool to apply database migrations(for local development and then to apply on production servers) that support raw SQL queries. My requirements for the tool are

1. To be extensible to any database(like SQLServer, MySQL, SQLite, etc.)
2. To be able to run on both Windows and Linux.
3. Not tied to any particular language. Any application written in any language should be able to use this by just installing it and running commands to apply migrations.

I am wondering if there are any existing open-source free tools that I could build on top or leverage them to some extent. Any inputs appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you're looking for liquibase or flyway

Comment: How about SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @mikeb Liquibase seems good but Flyway is expensive. I basically want to use something like Liquibase and build on top of it acc to my needs. Do you know if Liquibase goes well with projects from any other languages?

Comment: @renderbox Thank you. I took a look at it but it looks like it is closely tied to python applications. I do not want that. I want my tool to be language independent

Comment: You can package a python tool into an exe for windows or add an entry point on the setup.py file for linux.  You have to build the tool in something. ;)